# Mutate spark data frame with custom function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is a spark dataframe `df` with schema:

```
{
    'objects' : [{'name': 'a', 'age': 10, 'is_relevant': False},
                 {'name': 'b', 'age': 20, 'is_relevant': True},
                 {'name': 'c', 'age': 30, 'is_relevant': False}]
}
```

How can I add new column `relevant_ages` to `df` which will contain age of relevant object? (there is *exactly one* relevant object in each row's `'objects'`)

Expected result is:

```
{
        'objects' : [{'name': 'a', 'age': 10, 'is_relevant': False},
                     {'name': 'b', 'age': 20, 'is_relevant': False},
                     {'name': 'c', 'age': 30, 'is_relevant': True}]
        'relevant_ages': 30
}
```

I am using `df.withColumn('relevant_names', my_udf(df.objects))` and having trouble with `my_udf`.

I tried different approaches, for ex.:

`my_udf = udf(lambda x: [o['age'] for o in x if o['is_relevant']][0], IntegerType())`

Comment: Your UDF code is OK. Could you please post `df.printSchema()` result? What spark version are you using and what is error message when you apply UDF?

Comment: Oh that worked indeed, sorry! I was trying 
`my_udf = udf(lambda x: [o.get('age', None) for o in x if o.get('is_relevant')][0], IntegerType())` and this did not work. I guess there is no .get() method implemented for lists in spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is actually working, though I found out that spark list fields have no .get() method, i.e. this code below will not work:

`my_udf = udf(lambda x: [o.get('age', None) for o in x if o.get('is_relevant')][0], IntegerType())`